# Should we delete pointers which point to the protobuf messages?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, smart-pointers

This is the code.

```
message Bar {}
```

```
int vec_size = 100;
std::vector<Bar*> vec;
vec.reverse(vec_size);
for (int i = 0; i < vec_size; i++) {
    vec.push_back(new Bar());
}
// other code. 
//call some functions;

// I think we need to do this if the vec is no longer used.
for (int i = 0; i < vec_size; i++) {
    delete vec[i];
}
```

As known to all, we need to free memory allocated with new. But I'm not sure whether protobuf message is different from others.

Moreover, is it a good idea if we replace `std::vector<Bar*>` with  `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>`?

Comment: Either `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` (depending on use case) would be better. You might not even actually need any dynamic allocations. But yes, you would need to `delete` those. General rule of thumb: for every `new` there should be a corresponding `delete`

Comment: This looks like a typo: `vec.reverse(vec_size);`. In order of prefered solution: No pointers at all, use `std::vector<Bar>`. Use `unique_ptr`. Use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Just say "no" to Pointless Use Of Pointers. Create a `std::vector<Bar>`, and completely forget about `new` and `delete`. That's `std::vector`'s job to worry about.

Comment: Your code shows nothing of protobuf (or if you use it GRPC) so what has your question to do with protobuf messages?